# MS Access when linking I get an strange field number

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

When linking CSV files to MS Access 2007 I get some fields with **#NUM!**

Why do I get this?

I was thinking that it is probably because I have fields with the following numbers `9999999999` and the data type i use is `_long Integer_`, but how can I get the actual number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it probably because I have fields with the following numbers 9999999999 the data type i use is long Integer

Yes. The largest positive value that will fit in a Long Integer column is

2,147,483,647

so

9,999,999,999

won't fit. You will either need to change the column type to

Field size: Decimal
Precision: 10
Scale: 0

or store the values as Text.

Comment: Actually yes, Double will be able to precisely store integer values of that magnitude.

Comment: Gord can you please help me with a similar question please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929608/obiee-exported-csv-and-when-importing-to-access-i-get-an-error)