# OBIEE exported csv and when importing to Access I get an error

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g, obiee

I have a report on OBIEE, the *date* field I made it Custom format to **MM-DD-YYYY** I have also try **[FMT:dateShort]**. Once I exported to .csv I am Linking the file with MS Access 2007 and the date field I get an error **#NUM!** why is that ?

Comment: If you have control over the formatting of the dates on the OBIEE report then why not just use `yyyy-mm-dd` format? That's probably the safest to use because it is unambiguous and easiest for applications to accept.

Answer (score 0):

**Either one of these could be the problem/solution:**

The #Num! in Access is telling you the cell contains a mix of data; some digitit, some text, for example: 34G (or your '-') would throw a #Num!

You need to go back to the Excel and change the format of any cell containing both numbers and text to "mixed data" then save that sheet before importing to Access.

You can do this with a Macro:

```
Sub Addspace() 
  Dim cell As Object 
  For Each cell In Selection 
    cell.Value = " " & cell.Value 
    cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1) 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Simply highlight cells needing the formatting, run the above macro, then re-save spreadsheet.

**Or:**

The #Num! error value means that the value in the field is too large (either positively or negatively) to be stored in the field, based on the field's DataType or FieldSize property setting. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209132)

Based on your format of the dates, I would try the first fix before anything else. Date =/= Number

Comment: It's very weird, I just imported the date as text to MS Access and for now its working ok. I will try to replace the - with a / and see if it works.

Comment: Text would make sense for the first reason above as it would be all inclusive of all characters that perhaps number would not.